# html5 canvas animate bezier curve endpoint

Tags: html, animation, canvas, endpoint, bezier

I want to animate the endpoint of a bezier curve to x,y coordinates in an html5 canvas without redrawing the entire stroke.  Basically, I need to make the endpoint look as though it is draggable, and when dragged, affects the length of the line.

This is my current standard bezier stroke code:

```
   var canvas = document.getElementById("myCanvas"),
       context = canvas.getContext("2d"),
       controlX1 = 140,
       controlY1 = 10,
       controlX2 = 388,
       controlY2 = 10,
       endX = 388,
       endY = 170;

   context.moveTo(188, 130);
   context.bezierCurveTo(controlX1, controlY1, controlX2, 
   controlY2, endX, endY);
   context.lineWidth = 10;
   context.strokeStyle = "black";
   context.stroke();
```

Does anyone have any ideas how this can be accomplished without using a library like Raphael; however, I am using jQuery, so that is an available resource.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> without redrawing the entire stroke.

That's not possible. The way you animate things in HTML5 Canvas is by (clearing and) redrawing them.

> library like Raphael

For the record, Raphael uses SVG, not HTML5 Canvas, and SVG makes this sort of thing much easier because it is a retained drawing surface.

Canvas is an immediate drawing surface. As soon as you draw something (like a curve) the canvas has no knowledge of what was drawn or where it is. You have to keep track of *everything* yourself. I feel like I parrot this a lot but I wrote a simple tutorial on learning to retain the necessary information to make canvas feel persistent like SVG that can be found [here](http://simonsarris.com/blog/510-making-html5-canvas-useful).

That being said, you might be better off using SVG (and not Canvas) if your planned app/site is not going to be very complex or intensive.

Comment: can I create an SVG 'canvas type' overlay on my document body that can be destroyed when I don't need it anymore?  Ideally, my curve stroke will lay ontop of some elements until the user closes the view then it will disappear, in which case I want to destroy the svg container.

Comment: Yes, all SVG elements are just like regular DOM elements on the page that you can create/destroy/show/hide and position however you like. Have a look at these examples: http://www.w3schools.com/svg/svg_examples.asp